# How should I go about inserting a full .lic or .licx file into a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb, licensing

I want to test MongoDB as a possible alternative to my file system set-up. I have 3 folders, two hold JSON data (so no problem there), but one holds .lic and .licx files. I simply want to store and retrieve these files easily from a MongoDB collection in a database. I'm testing on the command line... How would I insert a .licx file into a collection that is in a database?

I've tried a command line argument

I've read a bit about gridFS but no clear example of how to use it.

```
--db license-server --collection licenses --type BSON --file C:\Users\<myname>\Desktop\<projectname>\private\licenses\<filename>.licx
```

I expect the licx file to be inserted into the collection with an id so I can retrieve it later.

I'm getting: error validating settings: unknown type bson as an error for the command line command.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a document that's bigger that 16MB or has an extension like .licx for example, run the command

```
mongofiles -d license-server put <filename(includingfullpath)>.licx
```

this will store the file in the fs.files and fs.chunks collections within your database.

To retrieve the file on the command line use

```
mongofiles -d license-server get <filename(includingfullpath)>.licx
```

Additional Documentation can be found here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/#bin.mongofiles